# Why so many SF works includes transparent LCD screens?

Tags: technology, minority-report

"Minority Report" is the first thing, that comes to my mind. But, of course, there are so many other SF examples... as well as many CSI-like-absolutely-no-SF-movies etc.

Why? What is the reason for telling people, that using screens, viewports etc. with transparent background and all the things seeing behind is useful, when it isn't useful at all. It makes your eyes tired and it makes you less focused to details, disoriented etc.

Is there any SF book or movie, that in particular addresses this topic -- i.e. contains reasonable explanation, why such screens are used or an attempt to prove, that they're better than nowadays non-transparent screens?

Comment: Because it's futuristic and super cool!

Comment: http://www.oled-info.com/transparent-oleds their real now. http://lumineq.com/en/products/tasel

Comment: In addition to the Rule of Cool, it's probably easier to do camera angles if your actors can be seen through their screens.

Comment: The question says "SF works" but I doubt you find this in SF books/stories much if at all.  Only in movies, because it looks cool.

Comment: @GEdgar yeah I can't really imagine any author over the age of twelve adding something like _and you could totally see straight through the lcd screen, like it was clear glass, but it's not. Trust me, it looks sweet_

Comment: @Himarm I know. See my question. See CSI part. CSI ain't no SF, right?

Comment: @GEdgar Do you mean, that transparent LCDs were Minority Report movie invention only and there is no such thing in the book (never read it actually)?

Comment: I remember Spock using a transparent screen when conducting his Memory Test at the beginning of Star Trek IV in 1986 - it was definitely a Rule of Cool moment. I don't think this was an LCD screen, however, but rather a projection onto a glass pane.

Comment: @trejder Dick's stories aren't really about technology - sometimes guys soot lasers instead of guns and travel using rockets or sth like flying cars. Although there exceptions Minority Report isn't one of them.

Comment: Filming through windows or other transparent surfaces that contain writing, reflections, or other visual information that is then superimposed on the character being filmed is very common. This is just the modern sci-fi equivalent filmmaking technique, made possible (or possibly just made easier) by advances in CGI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the question in-universe, no, there is no reason to have clear, see-through screens.

Out-of-universe, as noted in some of the comments, it's so that viewers can see the characters better.  Here's a TVTropes article about it: [In Space Everyone Can See Your Face](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InSpaceEveryoneCanSeeYourFace) *WARNING: TVTropes link*

Basically, the production company is paying these actors a lot of money, and they want to make sure they are getting their money's worth.

Comment: You explain nicely, why it is used in movies. Is that mean, that answer to my question is "No. There are no known SF works with proper explanation of using such thing"?